# Printing the values in an intList

Tags: java, arrays, output

I have an array 'store' that stores a number of LinkedLists called intList.

How do I print the values held in each list? I tried to print it as follows:

```
system.out.println(store[i].toString);
```

but get the following in return:

intList@16ad9f5d

or something similar.

Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: Please post the code that you've tried out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `java.util.LinkedList` has a nice `toString()` method (so no need to write it yourself, reinvent the wheel etc.), so most probably you don't call it at all. Seems like you're doing something like `toArray().toString()`, or maybe `store.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Extend `LinkedList` and implement `toString()`.

Comment: How do I do extend the linkedlist?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(List l : arr)
{
 Iterator it = l.iterator();
 while(it.hasNext())
   {
    System.out.println(it.next());
   }
}
```

Something like this might work...

Comment: syso it not a method.User has to use System.out.println()

Comment: Any person with basic java knowledge will understand that I meant system.out.println(). Anyways I will change it ... Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

```
Public class YourLinkedList<String> extends LinkedList<String> {
  //You code goes here or blank
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return Arrays.toString(this.toArray());
   }
}
```

You will get output as : [fdf, fdfdf, fdfdf]

Answer (score 0):

I think This code helps to you.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {


        LinkedList<Integer> l1=new LinkedList<Integer>();
        l1.add(1);
        l1.add(2);
        LinkedList<Integer> l2=new LinkedList<Integer>();
        l2.add(3);
        l2.add(4);
        LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> sort=new LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
        sort.add(l1);
            sort.add(l2);
        for(List l : sort)
        {
         Iterator it = l.iterator();


         while(it.hasNext())
           {
            System.out.println(it.next());
           }
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use iterator as this :

```
Iterator iter = yourList.iterator();

while(iter.hasNext()) {
   System.out.println(iter.next());
}
```